# ant build - not recognised as a command

Tags: java, ant

Im doing an ant build, the command i use is

```
ant clean compile war
```

and apache ant is included in the path too,

```
c:\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin;
```

This is my PATH variable:

```
PATH=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WIN
DOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\
System Center Operations Manager 2007\;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.8
.1\bin
```

Now i get this error message,

```
'"java.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: The PATH variable is set to C:\apache-ant-1.8.1\bin, but it should be version 1.8.2 per the OP, not 1.8.1. Sadly this doesn't help with my problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c:\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin` needs to be in your *system PATH* so that the shell can find it. Your classpath is irrelevant for this purpose.

You can add it at the prompt:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin
```

And you should be able to run `ant`.

But you want to persist this change so you don't need to type this every time. To do so you'll need to add it to the list of system or user variables. Follow the directions from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519):

1. Right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.
2. Click the Advanced tab.
3. Click Environment variables.
4. Click one the following options, for either a user or a system variable:

   - Click New to add a new variable name and value.
   - Click an existing variable, and then click Edit to change its name or value.
   - Click an existing variable, and then click Delete to remove it.

In step 4, add *;c:\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin* to the end of the value, being careful to note the semicolon which seperates this new entry from the preceding PATH elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and its PATH not the CLASSPATH. I meantioned it worngly in my question. As you said, i have it in my path and there is so space and properly terminated with semicolons...still it wouldnt work.

Answer (score 1):

First off, what if you execute this at the command prompt:

```
C> java --version
```

Do you get that error message?

I see you have `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin` in your PATH. Does that directory exist? Is there a file called `java.exe` in that directory?

If you can't execute `java.exe`, and the directory `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin` doesn't exist on your computer, you'll have to download Java from Oracle's website and install it on your Windows machine. Or, if you have Java on your computer, you'll have to modify the PATH environment variable, so that `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin` is replaced by the actual path of your `java.exe` command.

---

If you can execute `java --version` from the command line, we can play around with the batch script `ant.bat` that lives in `C:\ant-1.8.2\bin`. Copy `ant.bat` to `ant.backup.bat`, so you have a backup of the file.

Use a text editor like [Notepad++](http://notepadplusplus.org/) or VIM(http://www.vim.org) and not Notepad you get with Windows. Edit the file `C:\ant-1.8.2\bin\ant.bat`. Around line 130 is the line:

```
:runAnt
```

After this line, put the following two lines:

```
echo DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG Attempting to execute an Ant java process
echo on
```

This will turn on command echoing in the `ant.bat` file. In the next two or three lines, it will actually print out the java execution line that starts up Ant. (Ant is a Java program). See if you get the error message as it tries to execute that Java command. See what that command line says and see if you can execute it outside the batch file.

That will give us a better indication what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The ant bin directory needs to be in your PATH environment variable, not in your classpath

Comment: Its in the PATH variable sorry about that. I changed now.

Comment: Hmm ok go to a cmd prompt and type path, then post the results in your question?

Comment: Now i have updated the path and added java too PATH avriable . Now i see the java.exe is not recognised as error message.